# Does this sentence make sense? Correct use of the word constitute?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I was pretty sure this made sense but then I looked up the dictionary meaning of the word `constitute` and I wasn't so sure?

```
By continuing to use the website and/or the Services you constitute that you agree to 
these new terms of use.
```

Comment: No, it does not. What do you want to say ?

Comment: @jack Basically by continuing to use the website they agree to the updated terms of use.

Comment: It's an unusual rewrite of the acceptable: 'Your continuing to use the website and/or the Services  constitutes an agreement on your part to these new terms of use.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the word constitute with the sentence conveys the message but somehow seems like a misfit there.

If I have understood it correctly there is an update in the licence terms that you want to notify the user about, before proceeding further.

How about "Continuing the use of this website and/or services indicates that you have read and you agree to the new terms of use."

Comment: 'Constitute' sounds more like it carries the weight of the law than 'indicate'. But then we're into legal fields or grey areas, which are thankfully off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that .... **you conform to the new terms of use**

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm instead of to constitute. "to confirm" is transitive,
so you say to confirm something or to confirm + that-clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your continued use this website and/or services **constitutes** your agreement to abide by our new/updated terms of use.

Comment: Are you a mind-reader?

Comment: Didn't you just laugh? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the eight or so decent on-line dictionaries, I haven't found any mention of the availability of a that-clause after the verb 'constitute'.

I've looked for the precise string "constitute that" on the internet, and hardly ever in the first few pages of results is there an example of 'that' being used in its complementiser role. It usually occurs (as far as I have checked) in its determiner role, as part of a noun phrase constituting (oops) the complement of 'constitute' used as a link verb (as is seen by replacement with 'the'):

> Truth and reason constitute ***that*** intellectual gold that defies
>   destruction.
>
> grant an injunction restraining the person from engaging in conduct
>   that appears to the court to constitute ***that*** offence
>
> Vacancies in the council were filled to constitute ***that*** body as
>   follows

There *is* one early usage of the constitute + that-clause:

> Just because I live in Iowa, THAT DOESNT CONSTITUTE THAT I LIKE CORN
>
> doesnt it get annoying when you ask your parents, "whats for dinner?"
>   "corn" wow!! your my parents! you KNOW i dont like corn!

But I'd say that this doesn't constitute an authoritative source.

Answer (score 0):

Consider simply saying:

> *By continuing to use the website and/or the services, you agree to these new terms of use*.